# Rails Query Joins and Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an app for this scuba school that has muiltiple locations and muiltiple courses at each school. I am trying to make it so users can find all the courses taught by a particular instructor, at a particular school (oh boy). The schema is as follows:

```
 create_table "courses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "course_name"
    t.integer  "course_number"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "teacher_id"
    t.integer  "school_id"
  end

  create_table "teachers", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "fname"
    t.string   "lname"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "school_id"
  end
```

I have the following relationships set up:

```
courses belong_to school
courses belong_to teacher

teacher belong_to school

school has_many courses
school has_many teachers
```

I have no clue how to do this, but this is my (idiotic) attempt:

```
#I need to match these queries where course.teacher_id is equal to teacher.id
teachers = Teacher.where('fname ILIKE ? OR lname ILIKE ?', params[:fname], params[:lname])
courses = Course.where('school_id = ?', params[:id])

#now to join the above queries
courses_offered_by_searched_teacher_at_specified_school = courses.joins(teachers)
```

I hope you are able to follow what I am trying to do. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you are supposed to use [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables):

```
Course.joins(:teacher).where('(teachers.fname ILIKE ? OR teachers.lname ILIKE ?) AND courses.school_id = ?', params[:fname], params[:lname], params[:id])
```